# Custom post type query by metabox value

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, meta-boxes

I've created a custom post type for "portfolio" with a custom metabox with a lot of extra fields, one of which is a checkbox that I'm using to determine whether this post type contains a case study, but I've hit a snag and I can't see where I've gone wrong. The output for the checkbox is either 'yes' or ''.

The setup in my metabox build is:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="rccustom_fields[case_study]" value="yes" <?php if ( isset($meta['case_study']) && $meta['case_study'] === 'yes' ) echo 'checked'; ?>>
```

And I can see the values exist as expected by outputting:

```
$meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'rccustom_fields', true );
 print_r($meta);
```

BUT, when I pull a basic WP query with args to filter those results:

```
$args = array(
'numberposts'   => -1,
'post_type'     => 'portfolio',
'meta_key'      => 'case_study',
'meta_value'    => 'yes',
```

I get nothing returned, even though doing the print_r shows me that the meta value does indeed exist and is equal to 'yes'. (if I comment out the meta_key/meta_value lines, all posts from the custom post type do display)

Anybody see something I don't here?

Comment: All the custom fields are wrapped into the rccustom_fields array to make saving them easier (at least that's my understanding -- working off something I built a while ago and the logic's a little fuzzy) ... If I were to query meta_key => 'rccustom_fields', I have no idea how I'd reach inside that array to test for meta_value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code , It may help to you.

```
$args_portfolio = array (
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'case_study',
            'value' => 'yes',
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
    ),
);

$data_portfolio = new WP_Query( $args_portfolio );
```

Comment: Yes, this should work, but for some reason it's not. I'm going to go back and rewrite the entire custom meta box and remove the array. I know doing it field-by-field with a long-form save function will work and can't really afford any more time to fiddle here. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone...  I wasn't able to find an elegant way to incorporate this additional filter into my query, but because the custom post type for this project will have very few ( less than 30 ) posts, I opted to simply add an IF statement inside my loop to filter for only posts matching the `case_study` field:

```
$portfolio_query = new WP_Query( $args_portfolio );


if( $portfolio_query->have_posts() ) :

    echo '<ul>';

    while( $portfolio_query->have_posts() ) : $portfolio_query->the_post();
        
    $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'rccustom_fields', true );

        if ( isset( $meta['case_study'] ) ) :
            the_title();
        endif;

    endwhile;

    echo '</ul>';

endif;
```

It feels clunky to me to do it this way rather than finding a way to filter the query, but in the interest of moving on with this page, it do.